# Issue querying NY Times Geography API

Tags: api

I'm having some issues querying the NY Times Geographic API and am wondering if someone can let me know what I am doing incorrectly. I would like to query articles originating from a specific distance from lat/long location OR query a bounding box.

If I enter the query URI in the browser bar, as such:

```
 http://api.nytimes.com/svc/semantic/v2/geocodes/query.json?nearby=38.920833,-94.622222&api-key=MY_KEY
```

I get:

```
{
"status": "ERROR",
"copyright": "Copyright (c) 2015 The New York Times Company. All Rights Reserved.",
"errors": ["global name \u0027lat\u0027 is not defined"],
"results": []
}
```

If I use the API Builder, I get the following, regardless of whether I provide a filter.

```
{
"status": "ERROR",
"copyright": "Copyright (c) 2015 The New York Times Company. All Rights Reserved.",
"errors": [
"Specify at least one filter"
],
"results": []
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: How are you passing the parameter MY_KEY? Is that a variable you've defined?

Comment: For testing purposes, I simply replaced it with my API key.  Eventually I'll add it to the process.ENV variable